# How to do a REST query on UUID data with booleans

Tags: rest, firebase

I'm having trouble creating a query using the `REST API` of Firebase.
I have 3 lists with the following structure.

```
"teams": {
    "team-one": {
     "name": "Team One"
     "image": "team-one.jpg"
    },
    "team-two": {
     "name": "Team Two"
     "image": "team-two.jpg"
    },
    "team-three": {
     "name": "Team Three"
     "image": "team-three.jpg"
    }
}
"staff": {
  "uuid-123456": {
    "firstName": "John"
    "lastName": "Doe"
  },
  "uuid-878787": {
    "firstName": "Jane"
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }
},
"team-members": {
  "team-one": {
    "uuid-123456": true,
    "uuid-878787": false
  },
  "team-two": {
    "uuid-123456": false,
    "uuid-878787": true
  },
  "team-three": {
    "uuid-123456": true,
    "uuid-878787": true
  }
}
```

In team-members I've defined the following rules

```
"team-members": {
  "$team": {
    ".indexOn": ".value"
  }
}
```

I'm now trying to create a `REST` request to retrieve all the UUID's that are true from a certain team. But I just don's seem to find the right way to do this. Also the Firebase docs aren't really helpful.

URL: `https://dummyproject.firebaseio.com/team-members/team-one.json?orderBy="$value"&equalTo="true"`

If someone could help me out with this one, that would be great, also... if possible I would like to know how you would create a `JOIN` or something on the `staff` data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the double quotes around the true for it to be treated as a boolean instead of a string.

```
https://dummyproject.firebaseio.com/team-members/team-one.json?orderBy="$value"&equalTo=true
```

And for the "join" I would probably go with duplicating some of the staff data so you can retrieve it in one single query.